# Spring-Batch does not open FlatFileItemWriter if bean is declared as ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch 4.3.8 and I'm trying to use the following code in my configuration to define a ItemWriter

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemWriter<MyData> itemWriter(MyFileConfig fileConfig) {
    String outputFileName = fileConfig.retrieveOutputFileName();
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(outputFileName)) {
        return new MyOtherWriter<>();
    }
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<MyData>().name(WRITER_NAME)
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(outputFileName))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter(DELIMITER)
            .names(NAMES)
            .build();
}
```

but I'm getting the following error when `outputFileName` is not blank

```
org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractFileItemWriter.write(AbstractFileItemWriter.java:239)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:413)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.task.TraceApplicationRunner.run(TraceApplicationRunner.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
```

Yet this code is working fine

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<MyData> itemWriter(MyFileConfig fileConfig) {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<MyData>().name(WRITER_NAME)
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(fileConfig.retrieveOutputFileName()))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter(DELIMITER)
            .names(NAMES)
            .build();
}
```

so I'm assuming the issue is that Spring Batch is not checking that the ItemWriter is actually a FlatFileItemWriter and doing the proper init. Is there a way to comfortably handle this case, without duplicating config (the various `@Conditional` annotations on beans)?

Comment: Be specific with the return type as yuou noticed. The configuration classes are processed very early on and they can only determine what to do based on the return-type of the method as there is no actual instance of the class that is being returned. Hence you need to be specific. So unless your own custom itemwriter is also an `ItemStreamWriter`  your only option is to create 2 configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Java configuration style to define step scoped `ItemStream` beans, the return type of the bean definition method should be at least `ItemStream`. This is required so that Spring Batch correctly creates a proxy that implements this interface, and therefore honors its contract by calling `open`, `update` and `close` methods as expected.

This is mentioned in the documentation here: [Scoping ItemStream components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#scoping-item-streams)